# How do I design an object in such a way I could formulate a JSON like this?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, data-structures

My problem is pretty simple. I think I am just missing something. I basically want to iterate and add things to an object so that I could eventually get a JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "user1": [{
        "idm": [{
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "email": "user1@example.com"
        }],
        "em": [{
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "email": "user1@example.com"
        }],
        "fm": [{
            "name": "Jane Smith",
            "email": "user1@example.com"
        }]
    }],
    "user2": [{
        "idm": [{
            "name": "John Smith",
            "email": "user2@example.com"
        }],
        "em": [{
            "name": "John Smith",
            "email": "user2@example.com"
        }],
        "fm": [{
            "name": "John Smith",
            "email": "user2@example.com"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I tried to make the `idm`, `em`, and `fm` arrays then pushing those into my object but I get an error 
`ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference`.

I am sure there is something that I am missing.

```
userData = {};
user = 'user1'

this.idm['name'] = name;
this.idm['email'] = email;
this.userData[user].push(this.idm);

this.em['name'] = name;
this.em['email'] = email;
this.userData[user].push(this.em);

this.fm['name'] = name;
this.fm['email'] = email;
this.userData[user].push(this.fm);
```

After update:

```
this.userData = {};
array = ['user1', 'user2']
var i
for(i=0:i<array.length; ++i){
this.userData[array[i]] = []

    this.idm['name'] = name;
    this.idm['email'] = email;
    this.userData[user].push(this.idm);

    this.em['name'] = name;
    this.em['email'] = email;
    this.userData[user].push(this.em);

    this.fm['name'] = name;
    this.fm['email'] = email;
    this.userData[user].push(this.fm);
}
```

My output in the console looks something like:

```
[object Object]
-user1
--0
---name "Jane Smith"
---emial "user1@example.com"
--1
---name "Jane Smith"
---emial "user1@example.com"
--2
---name "Jane Smith"
---emial "user1@example.com"
-user1
--0
---name "John Smith"
---emial "user2@example.com"
--1
---name John Smith"
---emial "user2@example.com"
--2
---name John Smith"
---emial "user2@example.com"
``
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the array like :

```
user = 'user1'
this.userData = { [user]: [] }; // or this.userData = {}; this.userData[user] = []

this.idm['name'] = name;
this.idm['email'] = email;
this.userData[user].push(this.idm);

...
```

Comment: I am getting a little weird behavior. So I can successfully do this.userData[user][0] for idm and  this.userData[user][1] for em but when I try to do this.userData[user][2] for fm I get undefined. I print the entire userData right before my call to access the fm data to my console and I see that it is there. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: added some things

Comment: @newwebdev22 I see your update, You write `this.userData[user]` instead `this.userData[array[i]]`

Comment: hmm I am still having the same issue. I just dont know why I can properly access 2 of the 3 arrays inside the object and not the last

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined userData as array.

```
userData=[]; idm=em=fm=[];
idm.push({name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"},{name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"});
em.push({name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"},{name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"});
fm.push({name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"},{name:"Jane Smith", email:"user1@example.com"});
userData.push(idm);
userData.push(em);
userData.push(fm);
```